OpenVPN Service wont connect
On Windows Server 2019 machine i have installed OpenVPN GUI and OpenVPN Service.
OpenVPN GUI works fine and connects to server using config from folder C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config.
Now i want to make OpenVNP works permanently as Windows service. So i run OpenVPNService.
But it wont connect. In logs i found only this:
2024-08-28 16:06:32 OpenVPN 2.5.5 Windows-MSVC [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Dec 15 2021
2024-08-28 16:06:32 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
2024-08-28 16:06:32 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021, LZO 2.10

But there are in Event Log no entries about connection to server.
Did i miss something?
